# pathlib.Path.mkdir() won't make directory at specified path

Tags: python

Having trouble with Path.mkdir() using:

```
Path('C:\\Users\\', user, 'Desktop\\py\\', folder, '\\', str(x).rstrip('.bmp')).mkdir()
```

ignores its path and makes the directory at C:/ such as in the following:

```
"C:/directory_created_here"
```

rather than:

```
"C:/Users/user/Desktop/py/folder/directory__created_here"
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to have `\\` between your path segments. `pathlib` handles that part. What you've done causes Python to take the `'\\'` segment as the start of the path, discarding everything before it (except the `C:` drive setting).

Also, `rstrip('.bmp')` doesn't do what you think it does - it strips all `.`, `b`, `m`, and `p` characters from the right side of the string, rather than discarding a trailing `.bmp`.

Your call should look something like

```
Path('C:\\Users', user, 'Desktop\\py', folder, str(x)).with_suffix('').mkdir()
```

or

```
Path('C:\\Users', user, 'Desktop\\py', folder, x).with_suffix('').mkdir()
```

if `x` is already a string.

Comment: You legend!  I'd figured out that "\\" was causing the problem but didn't know what exactly was happening. Also I couldn't figure out a better alternative to 'rstrip()' so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like so

```
import os

user = 'my_name'
folder = 'new_folder'
x = 'test.bmp'

path_parts = [
    'C:',
    'Users',
    user,
    'Desktop',
    'py',
    folder,
    str(x).rstrip('.bmp'),
]

path = os.path.join(*path_parts)
os.makedirs(path)
```